# gcc assembler seems to use x86_64 even when '--32' specified

Tags: linux, kernel

I am building 32-bit linux kernel on 64-bit linux host. (version 2.6.9 both on host and the target).  I am doing the following:

```
make ARCH=i386 CFLAGS='-m32 -Iinclude/asm/mach-default' ASFLAGS='-march=i386 --32'
```

even I specified the ASFLAGS for make, I still got the following warning and errors:

```
  AS      usr/initramfs_data.o
  LD      usr/built-in.o
ld: warning: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `usr/initramfs_data.o' is incompatible with i386 output

<snip>
  AS      arch/i386/kernel/entry.o
arch/i386/kernel/entry.S: Assembler messages:
arch/i386/kernel/entry.S:145: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pushf'
```

the code at entry.S:145 is:

```
 pushfl                  # We get a different stack layout with call
                         # gates, which has to be cleaned up later..
```

Any ideas how can I make sure the AS is using i386 (32-bit), not x86_64?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory check of the linux kernel makefile seems to indicate to me that you should be using `AFLAGS`, not `ASFLAGS`.  Line 647 of my top-level kernel makefile says:

```
# Add user supplied CPPFLAGS, AFLAGS and CFLAGS as the last assignments
```

Comment: Thanks.  AFLAGS seems to be proper one. I also needed to use "-m32" instead of "--32" (even though "as" man page says --32).  Now it's making progress, but I hit some other problem. I will probably follow with a separate question.